# AppStore showing same app twice

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store, itunes

My application was just approved, but I notice when I search for it on my phone, it comes up twice.  Has any had this problem?  Not sure if it is really a bad thing, but just confusing.

App is called Little Tipper, and if you search it from a mobile device it will appear twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the AppStore. (Almost) all apps are twice in the AppStore at the moment:
http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2010/03/apple-app-store-bug.html

Comment: Thanks, it finally went away.  It was my first submission, and I could find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your app support both iPhone and iPad? If so, you are seeing a version for each device.

Comment: Nope, and i'm searching from my iPhone